# Ajax form validation refuses to work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation, forms

I'm trying to validate a form using ajax and it just won't work for me, so before I mess the thing up completely I thought I'd ask for some help before continuing, thanks in advance to anyone who can help :)

http://pastebin.com/0t53EE0g <- access.php

http://pastebin.com/nY0eVEx1 <- logIn.php

I'm sorry I can't elaborate more on what the problem might be because I genuinely don't know where I've gone wrong since I'm relatively new to the concept of AJAX, but I think the problem might be in the $.post function in access.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something like $query=mysql_query() between 20 and 21 in login.php

and you cant use 
header("Location: clientsTable.php");

after sending data

does this help?

Comment: the second point helps, but the class I made to validate the users does the query for me, but thanks for that second point :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem maybe that jQuery is passing in different things than your php script is expecting.  In your php script, you are checking the variables `$_POST['username']`, and `$_POST['password']`, but in your jQuery, you are sending form values `$row['username']` and `$row['password']`.  You need to change one of the other, and I recommend setting up your ajax submit like this:

```
$('#logbutton').submit(function(){
  $.post(
    "logIn.php",
    {
      username:$('#username').val(),
      password:$('#password').val(),
      rand:Math.random()
    },
    function(data) {
      if(data == 'yes'){
        alert('woop');
      }
      else{
        alert('try again');}
        return false;
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: What you said is correct :D thanks, now I just need to fix the other silly bugs I have, really appreciate it.